# jQuery Validate onclick: false not working for checkbox or select

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am trying to disable validation until submit after an error occurs. The onfocusout handler works fine, but onclick does not work for a checkbox or a select element.

I wrote the following up as a quick example. If you submit a blank form and then correct the checkbox and select, they should not validate immediately. You'll see the text input is working correctly.

The select seems to work sometimes, irregardless of the onclick handler. It did validate onclick in safari, did not in chrome.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebMdq/6/

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
Do you Rawk? <input type="checkbox" name="rock" /><br /> 
choose color: <select id="color" name="color" class="required">
<option value="">Choose One</option>
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="blue">red</option>
</select><br />
<input type="submit" />
</form>​

$(function () {
var validator = $("#myForm").validate({ 
             onfocusout: false,
             onkeyup: false,
             onlclick: false,
             rules: { 
                 fname: "required", 
                 rock: "required",
                 color: "required"
                }, 
             messages: { 
                 fname: "Enter your firstname", 
                 rock: "you know you do",
                 color: "pick one!",
             }, 
         });
});
```

Comment: Does this fiddle exhibit the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/jUDEk/? (PS, `onclick` still is not spelled correctly)

Comment: No, it doesn't, but how?

Comment: There's not a typo in it `:)`

Comment: Clearly my 14 hours in today have not been good for my problem solving abilities. So sorry to waste your time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Select, radio, and checkboxes have inconsistent event behavior across different browsers.

change or onchange event is used for radio/checkboxes.